# Prove: $\frac{p}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{\sin xt}{t\cdot \sin\frac12pt}\sin([\frac xp]+\frac12) pt \, \mathrm dt=\cdots$

Tags: integration, analysis, limits

Suppose $p>0$, define that
$$
g(x)=\begin{cases}
p\left\lfloor\frac xp\right\rfloor+\frac p2,x\geqslant0\\\\-g(-x), x<0\end{cases}$$
Prove 
for all $x$,

> $$ \frac{p}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\sum_{n=-\lfloor x/p\rfloor}^{\lfloor x/p\rfloor}\frac{\sin ((n+\frac12)pt)}{\sin (\frac12pt)}\cdot\frac{\sin (xt)}{t} \, \mathrm dt=\frac12[g(x^+)+g(x^-)].$$

First,

$$\sum_{n=-\lfloor x/p\rfloor}^{\lfloor x/p\rfloor}\frac{\sin ((n+\frac12)pt)}{\sin (\frac12pt)}\cdot\frac{\sin (xt)}{t}=\frac{\sin (xt)}{t\cdot  \sin(\frac12pt)} \sin\left(\left\lfloor \frac xp\right\rfloor+\frac12\right) pt ,$$

I just simplify it, then get

$$\frac{p}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{\sin (xt)}{t\cdot \sin(\frac12pt)} \sin\left(\left(\left\lfloor \frac xp\right\rfloor+\frac12\right) pt\right) \, \mathrm dt=\frac12[g(x^+)+g(x^-)].$$

However, I don't know how to continue it. I guess that it may be related to $fourier.$

Can someone help me out? Sincerely thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by [x/p]?  And could you add some ()?  Terms like sin(x+y)p  are interpreted by my mind as p*sin(x+y) whereas I think that you mean sin((x+y)*p) ?

Comment: @rrogers,Sorry, I have corrected them, thank for your reminding.

Comment: Can you give me a reference for the summation?  I did the integration and did not get your answer.  Perhaps a pi is missing or some such?

Comment: @rrogers I just expand $\displaystyle\sum_{n=-\lfloor x/p\rfloor}^{\lfloor x/p\rfloor}\sin ((n+\frac12)pt)$, as you can see, it is symmetric about $0$

Comment: That boils down to just showing that $$\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{\sin(nx)}{n}$$ is the Fourier series of the sawtooth wave, that is pretty well-known.